# html5 geolocation method to detect if coord is in area circle?

Tags: html, geolocation, gps

I know the method watchPosition() and check if the distance between current location and set arrival location is < 10 meters so you can popup a message like You're home!

But... curious...

Is it possible, does a function excists, to set a circle around the arrival point with option r=10 meter and let detect if the current location (watchPosition()) is in it?

I am asking because several times I made a script with many lines and discovered later a function with one or two lines does the same trick...